# Exclude method not functioning in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a task which excludes certain files from all tasks which have exclude method like Copy , Jar etc..

```
task excluder<<{
    def alltasks = project.getAllTasks(true).get(project)

    for(def t in alltasks){
        try{
            println t.name
            t.exclude([f])
            println f
        }
        catch(MissingMethodException e){}
    }
    println 'excluded files'
}
```

When I explicitly mention the files to be excluded in the task, like `t.exclude(['a','b'])`, they get excluded. But if i pass a property in the exclude method, they do not get excluded.

In gradle.properties, I set `f='a','b'` and when i run the task test it does not exclude the folders 'a' and 'b'. 
It does not give any errors, and the `println f` method works just fine, it prints `'a','b'`

I would like to know why this is happening.

**EDIT**

I made these changes in my build.gradle after Björn Kautler's response
.
build.gradle

```
ext{
f="['a','b']"
}

project.tasks.withType(AbstractCopyTask) {
println it
println f
it.exclude(f)
}


task copier(type:Copy){
from 'src'
into 'C:/Documents and Settings/manoj.deshpande/Desktop/Destingation/Copy'
}

task jarer(type:Jar, dependsOn:copier){
from 'src'
archiveName = 'namer.jar'
destinationDir file('C:/Documents and Settings/manoj.deshpande/Desktop/Destingation/Jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you do not consider Gradle phases.

There is initialization phase where settings.gradle is executed and projects of a multi-project build are added to the build.

Then there is configuration phase where tasks are configured and stuff like excludes and so on are set.

And finally there is execution phase where the needed tasks are executed.

You try to change configuration in the execution phase which is really bad and prone to not working as you observed.

If you want to exclude stuff conditionally, do not do it via a task (which is also not guaranteed to run before the tasks you try to manipulate if you do not have task dependencies) but do it via some project property which you can also set from the commandline with `-P excludeShit=true`.

Then have something like the following in your build file **outside** any task

```
if (hasProperty('excludeShit') && excludeShit.toBoolean()) {
    project.tasks.withType(AbstractCopyTask) {
        it.exclude f
    }
}
```

This would exclude `f` from tasks of type Copy, Sync, Jar, Zip, Tar and similar.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.
Its my mistake for configuring tasks during execution phase.
I tried what you asked, but it still did not exclude when i tried exclude([f]), so I tried using exclude(['a','b']), and it worked. Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: If you didn't mistype here, I guess you should change `f='a','b'` to `f=['a','b']`.

Comment: I tried f=['a','b'] and still doesn't work.I'll just edit my question and show you how my build.gradle looks.

Comment: `f="['a','b']"` != `f=['a','b']`

Comment: Finally, It worked.
Really appreciate your help
f=['a','b'], this worked

Comment: It works when I put **f** in **ext** closure in build script.
How do I make it work from gradle.properties. When I add **f=['a','b']** in gradle.properties, it again does not exclude

Comment: My guess is that the value of **f** in gradle.properties is parsed as a string and not as a set. Right ? If so, should I manipulate the string to get what I desire ?

Comment: Yep, those properties files are plain properties files. If you want some transformation like that string to set etc. you either have to do it yourself, use a plugin that does it, or not use gradle.properties for that. You can also do `apply from: 'excludes.gradle'  and there use Groovy as if you were in the Gradle build file itself.

Comment: I have read it :).
If you are looking for an upvote, I do not have enough reputation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Ah, ok, forgot you have to have 15 rep to up-vote. :-)